# Enable Alpine to execute not-musl Java JRE on ARM64 arch

Tags: java, docker, glibc, arm64, alpine-linux

My goal is to enable Alpine to execute non-musl supported JRE. The motivation behind this is the image size minification, I have achieved a certain progress to compress the JRE itself but the minimal image I have found is ARM64v8/debian:slim-9 with 50M. it's pretty good, but not enough.
I didn't find to any JRE up to 9 for ARM64 with musl supported. therefor the possible direction is

1. Take the Alpine Image (around 5M)
2. Enable it to execute glibc Java code (by installing glibc APK)
3. Run JRE on the resulted image, hopefully, the final image size will be less than 20M.

Here my steps:

All my experiments I'm doing on the real ARM64 hardware.

- Pull Alpine 3.8
- Base on the following git project
  https://github.com/owlab-exp/alpine-pkg-glibc-arm64

  apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

  wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-2.23-r3.apk

  apk add  --allow-untrusted glibc-2.23-r3.apk

Copy the OpenJRE 10 folder with minified modules list using jlink tool to the Apline image with.

Unluckily, when I try to run ./java --version, I'm getting

```
/bin/sh: ./java: not found
```

I see that glibc apk was installed the following folder has been added

```
/usr/glibc-compat/lib
```

Any ideas what I'm missing will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Denis, could you post the output of `ldd ./java`?

Comment: Hi Viliano, sorry for the long delay, the ldd ./java output is

`/work/target/jlink-image/bin # ldd ./java
 /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x55689ab000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7fa0830000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x55689ab000)
 libjli.so => ./../lib/jli/libjli.so (0x7fa080f000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x55689ab000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x55689ab000)
Error relocating ./../lib/jli/libjli.so: __rawmemchr: symbol not found`

Comment: Thank Denis. How about `/usr/glibc-compat/bin/ldd ./java`? (the default `ldd` is the Alpine-musl one)

Comment: After apk install I don't see /usr/glibc-compat/bin/ folder, there are to folders under glibc-compat `etc` and `lib`

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that `ldconfig` is the missing bit. Running `ldconfig` will update the search paths of the dynamic linker, so it'll be able to find the installed glibc binaries.

For running glibc's `ldconfig` and pointing towards the installed glibc:

`/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib`

But, you've mentioned that there are only `lib` and `etc` folders under `/usr/glibc-compat`.
The glibc binaries are found in another apk, so you'll need to grab and install: `glibc-bin-2.23-r3.apk`.

Putting everything together, I've had success running glibc Java using the following (X86) Dockerfile:

```
# Based on stripped down Docker file from:
# https://github.com/anapsix/docker-alpine-java

FROM alpine:3.8

ENV GLIBC_REPO=https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc
ENV GLIBC_VERSION=2.28-r0
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# do all in one step
RUN set -ex && \
    apk --update add libstdc++ curl ca-certificates && \
    for pkg in glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION} glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}; \
        do curl -sSL ${GLIBC_REPO}/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/${pkg}.apk -o /tmp/${pkg}.apk; done && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/*.apk && \
    rm -v /tmp/*.apk && \
    /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib
```

Comment: thanks valiano again, let me try the same on arm64 arch

Comment: Hi Valiano, I tried to do what you have suggested,I managed to recompile glibc sources on ARM64, created apk file according to the Apline package creation guide. Finally I add there to alpine running container with running `ldconfig` unluckily still can't run the java process, probably I missed something. Will appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Hi @DenisVolohsin. Aren't you using the already built glibc ARM64 apk's? I would give these a try, first:
- https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-2.23-r3.apk
- https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-bin-2.23-r3.apk

Comment: No, I build it on ARM64 machine by myself from the source code.Thanks for the link, sure let me take a look, btw, just for the sake of experiment, I tried to run java 9, and 10 on the alpine image (X86) which I build from your script, the image seems ok, but only java 8 works on it.  10 and 9 returns `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:`, seems like there is something deeply in the newers java release which glibc doesn't support :(

Comment: back to your comment: the link you sent me is for x86, isn't? I was sure, I can't use it on ARM64, that's why I created custom alpine-pkg-glibc-builer image, then compiled the glibc source and base on the result created the alpine apk

Comment: @DenisVoloshin whops, sorry! My bad. I got mixed up since `alpine-pkg-glibc-arm64` forks `alpine-pkg-glibc` and they have the same readme, that sent me to the X86 link. About `ldconfig`, did you run this precisely: `/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib`? If so, could you post the output of `/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldd ./java`? (if I recall correctly, that's where glibc's `ldd` should reside)

Comment: yes, this repo a bit confusing it has allegedly ARM64 support but when you open APKBUILD , it supports only x86_64 and points to the x86_64 glibc stuff, I thought you can't use compiled x86_64 glibc for making arm64 alpine.

Comment: here is `/usr/glibc-compat/bin # ldd /work/target/jlink-image/bin/java
 /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x5558695000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7fad399000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x5558695000)
 libjli.so => /work/target/jlink-image/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so (0x7fad378000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x5558695000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x5558695000)
Error relocating /work/target/jlink-image/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __rawmemchr: symbol not found`

Comment: @DenisVoloshin hmm. Seems `libc.so.6` is resolved to the glibc you've built. What's the output of `objdump -T /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 | grep __rawmemchr`? It should be something like:
`0000000000096550 g    DF .text 0000000000000204  GLIBC_2.2.5 __rawmemchr`

Comment: @DenisVoloshin Wait, something's not right. Your `libc.so.6` is resolved to `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1`. I think that's wrong: it should resolve to `/lib/libc-linux-aarch64.so.1` (or whatever the built `libc.so` name is). It you'll dump `libc.so`, with `readelf -a libc.so | grep __rawmemchr`, you should see something like:
`5121: 0000000000096550   516 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _rawmemchr`
- That's the global `__rawmemchr` function.